# need SQLite3 for a portable program vb6

Tags: vb6, sqlite

Is there any idea to use **sqlite version 3** in vb6 like sqlite version 1 ? sqlite version 1 use `ags_sqlite.dll`

http://www.freevbcode.com/imagesvr_ce/184390/source/008/zully_lite_sqlite.zip

Comment: The SQLite library is just a normal DLL, but will require some changes to the calling convention to work with VB6 and unmangle the export names. I'm sure there are samples and descriptions around though.

Comment: Are you sure you "need" SQLite?  I just tested a VB6 ADO/Jet 4.0 program on machines from Win95 to Server 2008 R2 without having to install anything at all.

Comment: I'm using dhRichClient wrapper for sqlite from here http://www.thecommon.net/

Comment: dhRichClient wasn't so bad. but i want to use sqlite3 :)

Comment: @Omid: `dhRichClient` uses custom built `sqlite3.dll` -- one w/ stdcall exports

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the [SQLite ODBC driver](http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/). It works pretty darn well and allows the DSN-less approach, which makes app distribution easier.

The only to look out for is that it won't allow multiple statements in one call - thus you must call them separately.

Comment: But he asked for "portable" in his topic heading, which makes an ODBC driver impractical.

Comment: It's not perfect, but he can install the ODBC driver in the user's profile program load, then uninstall it on program unload.  The install/uninstall is a `rundll32.exe ...` command.

Comment: Are you sure ODBC drivers don't have to be registered in HKLM?  That requires admin rights, basically defeating the point of a "portable" application.

Comment: @Bob77 The first tab of the ODBC app is `User DSN`.  Looking at the registry, everything in `User DSN` is stored `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\ODBC`.  So I am going to guess, portable is still a go.

Comment: The driver itself requires HKLM registration though as far as I know, so no go.